# how to get the value of a HiddenFor control in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor-2

i have a hidden for control as

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SchedulingProfileDetails.Id)
```

I am trying to access the value in this hidden field in my jquery and then trying to pass the value to controller

```
  var id = $("#SchedulingProfile_Id").val();

                        $.ajax({
                            url: rootUrl + 'SchedulingProfile/SaveDetails',
                            type: "POST",
                            data: ({
                                schedulingProfileId: schedulingProfileId, 
                                   });
```

but I am getting null value in id. Please help me out

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I could be wrong, but isn't it merely that:

```
var id = $("#SchedulingProfile_Id").val();
```

needs to be:

```
var id = $("#SchedulingProfileDetails_Id").val();
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I'ts always good to check the generated HTML page, simply search for hidden input.

Also you are trying to pass schedulingProfileId to your AJAX call, I  think it should be:

```
$.ajax({
url: rootUrl + 'SchedulingProfile/SaveDetails',
type: "POST",
data: ({
    schedulingProfileId: id, 
       });
```