# Get @Html.HiddenFor VALUE using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a JavaScript function that sets a ViewBag value whenever you mouse up on a radio checkbox. I'm trying to submit the ViewBag in a hidden field on my form.

My JavaScript function is successfully getting the id. But I'm unable to get that value into my hidden form. I think my first problem is i'm using a ViewBag when I should be using a different type. But this is where I'm hoping to get some assistance. How can I set a value in a JavaScript and get that in a @Html.HiddenFor()?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('body').on('mouseup', 'td', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.id)) = id;
        });
    });


@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id, new {id = "id", Value = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.id)) })
```

***UPDATE WORKING SOLUTION BELOW****

I'm marking @Ali Soltani solution as the correct answer. His answer lead me in the right direction. Here is my full working code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('body').on('mouseup', 'td', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = parseInt($(this).attr("id"));
            $("#Id").val(id);
        });
    });
```

Form:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id, new { id = "Id" })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get the value of a HiddenFor control in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007083/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-hiddenfor-control-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the value attribute of a hidden input tag by selecting it using the property name and using the jquery val() method.

```
$("#id").val(id); // id in $("#id")
```

You should use `$("#id")` because you used `model.id`. Second `id` is `var id = $(this).attr("id");` and just you need razor code like this if `id` in `model.id` is unique:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)
```

Comment: Thanks Ali for the response. I tried your solution, but i'm still unclear how the HiddenFor value would be getting the id from my function? Shouldn't I be setting the id value somewhere in the HiddenFor? Each time i select the radio button, a new id would be present. Depending on which radio is option is selected, that should be in my form.

Comment: I did a little more configuring and I see what you mean now. I updated my question above. Thanks for your help!