# ASP.NET Pass model data to site.js

Tags: javascript, html, razor, razor-pages

How to pass my model data from index.cshtml in site.js.
Trying to make Ajax request to View controller with model data.

I have model:

```
public class ParticipantDataList
{
    public List<ParticipantData> Data { get; set; }
}
```

which has ParticipantData in it:

```
public class ParticipantData
{
    public Guid LeadId { get; set; }

    public string FIO { get; set; }

    public Boolean isSelected { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried using HiddenFor to store the model:

```
@model Models.ParticipantDataList
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Data.Count; i++)
{ 
   @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Data[i])
}
```

or

```
@foreach (var participant in Model.Data)
{ 
   @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Data)
}
```

and using it in js:

```
var data1 = $("#Data").val();
```

So far I have data1 equals `System.Collections.Generic.List 1[Models.ParticipantData]` BUT data field equals null or data1 is unidentified

What did I do wrong, have read countless pages on Stack Overflow, but so far no luck.

Comment: Great you're trying! That's a good start. You need to show us that you're trying, rather than just tell us you are. Share your attempt, review [mcve], and clearly explain which part you're stuck on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get the value of a HiddenFor control in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007083/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-hiddenfor-control-in-jquery)

Comment: The id won't be `Data` look at the actual id of the control and then use that to access it

Comment: One of the key things to learn when working with ASP.NET is how the server-side code (like `@Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Data)`) is rendered on the browser (where JavaScript is run). When you go to the page with that code on it, open up the Developer Tools of your favorite browser and look at its Elements tab. You'll need to find where these hidden fields were rendered (it will start with `<input` and have `type="hidden"` in it. There you'll find the IDs of the elements are all different.

Comment: So the part you're actually struggling with is getting the values into variables in JavaScript? I think your first Razor example is closer - that should give you a hidden field for each ParticipantData in your model.  Then it's just a matter of writing some JavaScript to gather those up. Make sure you inspect the rendered HTML when you're writing your JavaScript. I personally wouldn't use HiddenFor here. You can do something like `<input type="hidden" id="ParticipantData-@i" value="@Model.Data[i].ToString()">`.

Comment: I'm assuming that you have an overload here for ToString that contains the information you want to utilize for your AJAX request. If not, it might need some tweaking, but that should get you started.

Comment: @Liam Unfortunately no, I have tried passing simple things like string and it worked, but struggling with passing whole Model or List of Objects.

Comment: @HereticMonkey My hidden value has a value of: `System.Collections.Generic.List 1[Models.ParticipantData]`, I probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Yep, that's the default implementation of `ToString`, as @mason was mentioning. You may want to consider just doing something like `<script>var model = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.Serialize(Model))</script>` Then you'd have a `model` JavaScript object that has the same properties as your C# model. Changes to it would not be reflected on the server (you'd need to use ajax or something to do that), but it might be easier to deal with.

Comment: @HereticMonkey @mason , thank you , but I haven't ever used <script/> tag and don't know where to put it, and furthermore how to pass this variable `var model` to my site.js file.

Comment: You can't pass a model into a hidden. They only hold strings, a model is an object

Comment: To build on what Liam said: you can't put an object in a hidden, but you can convert that object to some string that contains information about that object. JSON is a particularly good choice when working with JavaScript.

Comment: @mason, no, I meant how do I get to my serialized value `<script>var model = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.Serialize(Model))</script>` from site.js, while as to my understanding I should store Script on index.jshtml page. Serialization was the problem solver, thank you guys very much, but don't know how to get to value still.

Comment: As long as you have site.js referenced on your page via a script element, it can use variables that you set in a `<script>` block on your Razor page. Or you can use the hidden input approach and then you won't need a separate script block directly in your Razor, but you'll have to code your JavaScript in site.js to extract the values from the hidden inputs. I think you're getting overwhelmed and thus forgetting the basics of HTML and JavaScript. Break down your work into small steps and then tackle each step one by one. We've given you a lot of hints for you here to go try.

Comment: @mason Yes, that worked for me, thank you. Haven't had experience working with ASP.NET, JS, was really struggling here, thank you again.